# UTC time stamp in long form (YYYYMMDDhhmmss.mmmuuun) formatting

Tags: date, abap, utc, date-formatting

I use an OData Service to import data into SAP system. This is an OData example:

```
{
   "Id" : "",
   "Timestamp" : "/Date(1449479875000)/",
   "UserName" : "USER",
   "SourceSystemId" : "ANY"
}
```

Timestamp is defined as (see details [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/c43005898be34c8ca6c433635fbb18ca/1705%20500/en-US/60ff8b5544fdbf5de10000000a423f68.html))

> UTC time stamp in long form (YYYYMMDDhhmmss.mmmuuun)

When I upload this data to ABAP system, the timestamp results in

> 20.151.207.091.755,0000000

I don't understand how 1449479875000 becomes 20.151.207.091.755,0000000

How can I upload e.g. 20.1**8**1.207.091.755,0000000?
Can anybody give me some hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamp is in "milliseconds since the Epoch" (1 Jan 1970) format.  See https://www.epochconverter.com/

The date 2018-12-07 09:17:55.000 would be represented by /Date(1544174275000)/.